# how to show mapkit blue dot(user's location) at desired location?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, mapkit, user-location

I am using MapKit. I want to know how to get current user's location. The MapKit shows a blue dot at current user location.

I want to do something like this: The user location is showed on the map. I have a button which, on clicking again, gets the current user location and shows the blue dot there.

Do I need to use `locationManager` or just call the `mapView.showUserLocation=YES;` on the button's click event?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you want to show the current user location simply write

`[mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];`